# Doubt about proof of theorem giving the number of pairwise edge-disjoint spanning trees of a given simple connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

[image]
I understood that $T$ is one of the spanning trees which has disjoint edges compared to other $k-1$ edges. then, $T$ has $|V(G)|-1$ edges.

What does the author say in the underlined statement? Isn't it a trivial thing?we know that $|\mathscr P-1|\leq|V(G)|-1$. Is it follow from this inequality and pigeonhole principle? How do I prove the converse?Where will I get the converse?
I draw the example for the illustration of the theorem,[image]

dark blue edged and narrow red edged trees are two edge disjoint trees, what does the theorem say?

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: The author meant that there are at least $|\mathscr{P}|-1=p-1$ edges of $T$ that connects vertices from different classes in $\mathscr{P}$.  This is obvious if you collapse each $V_i$ to a point.

Comment: @shaun Textbook of graph theory Balakrishnan and Ranganathan

Comment: T is a spanning tree, so graph uses every verices of G, each vertices are connected, so, it must have n-1 edges. each edge, one end is in any one of the $V_j$. so it must have p-1 edges of T . right?@user10354138

Comment: Where can I find the converse?

Comment: what do you meant by this Tutte [181]; Nash-Williams [145]

Comment: user10354138 I Really don't understand the necessary condition.:(

Comment: Please try to select informative titles, see edit for an option.

Answer (score 1):

The highlighted sentence would be better if it said: whenever $V_1, V_2, \dots, V_p$ is  a partition of $G$, and $T$ is a spanning tree of $G$, $T$ must contain at least $p-1$ edges joining distinct parts.

One way to prove this claim is: if we delete all edges of $T$ that join distinct parts among the $V_1, V_2, \dots, V_p$, then $T$ becomes a forest with $p$ components (one on each $V_i$). But deleting one edge can only increase the number of components of a graph by at most $1$, so at least $p-1$ edges must be deleted to get from $1$ to $p$ components.

Another way, [as suggested in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2926342/doubt-on-theorem-4-4-4-tutte-181-nash-williams-145#comment6045357_2926342): consider the graph $T^*$ on $p$ vertices $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_p\}$ with an edge $v_iv_j$ whenever $T$ has an edge between $V_i$ and $V_j$. $T^*$ must be connected: if there were no way to get from $\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}$ to $\{v_{k+1}, \dots, v_p\}$ in $T^*$, there would be no way to get from $V_1 \cup \dots \cup V_k$ to $V_{k+1} \cup \dots\cup V_p$ in $T$. So $T^*$ has at least $p-1$ edges.

Once the claim is done, take the $k$ edge-disjoint spanning trees $T_1, T_2, \dots, T_k$ and apply the claim to them. Each $T_i$ has $p-1$ edges joining distinct parts of the partition $V_1, V_2, \dots, V_p$, and these must be different edges for each $T_i$ (because they're edge-disjoint). Altogether, we get $k(p-1)$ edges joining distinct parts, which was what we wanted.

Comment: How do I prove the converse?

Comment: @Mathgeek I don't know; it seems hard. Have you tried looking up the citations Tutte [181] or Nash-Williams [145] in your book? They should correspond to papers cited at the end of the book or at the end of the chapter.

Comment: proof is not given in the textbook. from where will i get this paper?

Comment: Tutte [181] or Nash-Williams [145], what does that mean?

Comment: It means that somewhere in your textbook, there is a list of papers cited, and number 181 on this list is a paper by Tutte that proves this theorem. The paper may or may not be available online, but without knowing what the citation is, nobody else can say.

Comment: You might also ask yourself whether you actually want to read a ten-page proof of the converse result if you do find it.

Comment: yes.I want to read